# Unbound (cachin dns resolver) not able to start in OEL 7 using systemd

Tags: dns, dnsmasq, resolver, unbound

I am trying to install and start unbound (caching dns resolver) using systemd but it failed with the error `unbound[19112:0] warning: did not exit gracefully last time (17277)`

OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.5 (Maipo)

Kernel: 4.14.35-1818.3.3.el7uek.x86_64

Here is my systemd service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Unbound DNS server
After=network.target
Before=nss-lookup.target
Wants=nss-lookup.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/unbound -c /etc/unbound/unbound.conf
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/unbound-control reload
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Did anybody face this issue before and has any solution ?

James

Comment: Did you look at logfiles, both systemd ones and unbound ones? That would be a first step, otherwise anything could have happened...

Comment: ya the only error i see is `unbound[19112:0] warning: did not exit gracefully last time (17277)`

Comment: Increase logging and restart your daemon. I doubt there is nothing else in the logfiles.